# MySql: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user using passwrod YES using cloud_sql_proxy

Tags: python, mysql, google-cloud-sql, cloud-sql-proxy

I need to execute a sql file using the mysql client in a python script (I can not execute the queries using a python mysql module), the database is a MySQL instance on GCloud, I'm connecting to that instance using `cloud_sql_proxy`.

I launched `my_sql_proxy` using tcp like so:

```
./cloud_sql_proxy -instances=<my_instance>=tcp:12367
```

And I'm trying to execute the sql script like so:

```
 gunzip -c <filename>.sql.gz 2>&1 | mysql --host=127.0.0.1 --port=12367 --user=<user> --password=<password> <dbmane>
```

This produces the following error:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user '<myuser>'@'cloudsqlproxy~<some ip>' (using password: YES)
```

I obviously checked user/pwd/instance are correct.

The same command pointing to a mysql instance actually hosted on localhost is working.

With the same `cloud_sql_proxy` process running I am able to connect using `Sequel Pro` client with the same auth info and I am able to connect to the db using the following command:

```
/rnd/pos/components/mysql --host=127.0.0.1 --port=12367 --user=<myuser> -p <dbname>
>>> Enter password:
>>> Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands....
```

When connected, this is the output (masked) of `SELECT USER(), CURRENT_USER();`

```
+--------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
| USER()                                     | CURRENT_USER()                                  |
+--------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
| <my user>@cloudsqlproxy~<same ip as above> | <my user>@cloudsqlproxy~<part of the same ip>.% |
+--------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
```

I tried with `-p[password]` and `--password[=password]`, same output.

Why the --password is blocking? Is it a `cloud_sql_proxy` config? Or is it a MySQL instance setting?
I googled and stackoverflowed but can't find anything relevant to my case.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suspect `mysql` looks for a socket by the default, while `cloud_sql_proxy` is explicitly using TCP.

I believe adding `--protocol=TCP` should solve the problem.
At least it helped me when I faced this obstacle under the same circumstances.